# SQL Person by month Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data set with

```
Name|ID|Start_DATE|END_DATE
```

I would like to get a break out of active months.

Example:

```
Bob Smith|1001|2016-12-01|2017-02-18
```

would return all the months listed between the dates

```
Bob Smith|1001|2016-12-01
Bob Smith|1001|2017-01-01
Bob Smith|1001|2017-02-02
```

I have been planing with some data based on dates I found. I will also need to deal with the active employees listed as `9999-12-31` once I figure out the base query.

```
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;

select @startDate = '20100101';
select @endDate = '20150531';

with dateRange as
(
  select dt = dateadd(mm, 0, @startDate)
  where dateadd(mm, 0, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(mm, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(mm, 1, dt) < @endDate
)
select *
from dateRange
```

Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: It seems to be a MySql question. Please tag it accordingly. It will attract more specific help to your question.

Comment: Nope, MS SQL was the intended audience

Comment: Are you asking if there is a better way to generate the dateRange?

Comment: I want the date range with the ID. I was just messing with the date range part of the equation. I found a solution for the dates but dont know how to incorporate the ID into that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question, here is one way to do it:

First, Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Name varchar(20), 
    ID int, 
    Start_DATE date, 
    END_DATE date
)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Bob Smith', 1001, '2016-12-01', '2017-02-18')
```

The DateRange calendar cte from your question, with dates that fits the sample data:

```
declare @startDate date;
declare @endDate date;

select @startDate = '20150101';
select @endDate = '20200531';

with dateRange as
(
  select dt = dateadd(mm, 0, @startDate)
  where dateadd(mm, 0, @startDate) < @endDate
  union all
  select dateadd(mm, 1, dt)
  from dateRange
  where dateadd(mm, 1, dt) < @endDate
)
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Name,
        ID, 
        CONVERT(char(12), Start_DATE, 107) As StartDate, -- just to see it clearly in the results
        CONVERT(char(12), END_DATE, 107) As EndDate, -- just to see it clearly in the results
        CONVERT(char(12), dt, 107) As ActiveMonth

FROM @T
INNER JOIN dateRange ON dt >= Start_DATE AND dt < END_DATE
```

Results:

```
Name        ID      StartDate       EndDate         ActiveMonth
Bob Smith   1001    Dec 01, 2016    Feb 18, 2017    Dec 01, 2016
Bob Smith   1001    Dec 01, 2016    Feb 18, 2017    Jan 01, 2017
Bob Smith   1001    Dec 01, 2016    Feb 18, 2017    Feb 01, 2017
```

BTW, there is a better way to create a calendar cte, using a numbers (or tally) table. [here a demo.](http://rextester.com/WKEY90703)